packages reinstall after xz-utils restore
how to fix my ubuntu from broken dependences issues everywhere after choas caused by xz-utils backdoor found few days ago. i am using noble development branch. After few updates days ago and lots of packages get stuck and cannot downgraded nor upgraded. Even i cannot see the kde login ui and lost the vim package. Today it seems the repo just open but after apt update and upgrade, the problem persists.
Please help to restore the os and I don't want to reinatall it. thanks!

Developement versions of Ubuntu are not supported on this site. Please don't use development versions of Ubuntu in production environments. Only use them if you are interested in reporting bugs are helping Ubuntu's development.

This issue is well-discussed in the developer and testing venues...which AskUbuntu is not.

The issues are not caused by xz-utils but the time_64t migration scheduled back in 2023 for end-March 2024 (Debian & Ubuntu) and covered in many ML posts... https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2024-March/042954.html https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2024-March/042955.html etc  The Xz/liblzma issue didn't impact Ubuntu noble unless you were using proposed packages - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/xz-liblzma-security-update-post-2/43801

Noble is not even beta yet. The dependencies (especially for KDE packages) are now totally messed up. Don't use development versions of Ubuntu in production environments.
To fix without reinstalling: Wait a few days till the repositories are sorted out, perform all updates and install the kubuntu-desktop package.

The issue was eventually fixed by April 5, 2024.

Will this work?   I think like ubuntu-mate-desktop & some other flavor desktops, there are still package issues with kubuntu-desktop, with packages still unavailable waiting build/rebuild (Xz/liblzma has just slowed this down as its caused rebuilds too ['in an abundance of caution'])

Right now, core packages like Dolphin got removed (in my test system), and cannot be installed due to dependency issues. For OP, the login UI got removed. Installing kubuntu-desktop will reinstall all these core packages, once it is installable (after the dependency issues are sorted out with new version of packages in the repositories).

Will try tomorrow see if it works and update here. BTW, is there any way I can tell if the repo is completely restored for Noble? right now, I can update but dependency issues still there.

Check for whether https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/dolphin lists an amd64 package. Right now, it does not. If it ever does, most likely the issue is fixed.

amd64 just ready on noble repo. I updated and installed kubuntu-desktop. Now everything comes back except I had to install chrome and vscode manually. But profiles still there. Thanks a lot!
